# Incrementing alphabet in batch-file

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, batch-file

I want to create a For loop to look if a program is on a flash drive, and copy a text file if it is. Since the drive letter varies on every PC, I want it to look at every drive letter.

```
if exist "D:\Test.exe" (
    copy "%FileName%.txt" "D:\" >nul
)
if exist "E:\Test.exe" (
    copy "%FileName%.txt" "E:\" >nul
)
if exist "F:\Test.exe" (
    copy "%FileName%.txt" "F:\" >nul
)
if exist "G:\Test.exe" (
    copy "%FileName%.txt" "G:\" >nul
)
Rem ...Continues possibly until drive Z or once it finds the file
```

Is there a way to create a For loop to increment the drive letter so I don't have to make an If statement each time?

Comment: `FOR %%G IN (A B C D etc...) DO IF EXIST "%%G:\test.exe" copy.....`

Comment: `for /L %%i in (65,1,90) do cmd /C exit %%i & if exist "!=ExitCodeAscii!:\test.exe" copy ...` with DelayedExpansion Enabled

Comment: @Aacini, you just made my day by a few seconds.  That is most sneaky and amusing code I have seen in a long time.

Comment: use `wmic` to determine your drive letters. `for /f "tokens=2*delims==" %%i in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption /value') do for /f "delims=" %%d in ("%%i") do if exist "%%d\test.exe" copy ...`

Comment: @Squashman: There is also `%=ExitCode%` variable that shows the %errorlevel% in Hexadecimal... **`;)`**

Comment: @Aacini, that is rather nice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a community wiki with all methods combined from the comments, per user.

[*`Squashman`*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1417694/squashman)

```
@echo off
FOR %%G IN (A B C D etc..Z) DO IF EXIST "%%G:\test.exe" copy
```

then, a very intuitive method using the exit codes `65` to `90` in ascii format, by [*`Aacini`*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778560/aacini).

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /L %%i in (65,1,90) do cmd /C exit %%i & if exist "!=ExitCodeAscii!:\test.exe" copy...
```

Then [*`my`*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7818749/gerhard) suggestion of using `wmic` to find all the actual drive letters available on the device:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2*delims==" %%i in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption /value') do for /f "delims=" %%d in ("%%i") do if exist "%%d\test.exe" copy ...
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate you giving multiple options. I ended up using your solution and it worked out great.